How to delete Goods in Qoo10 by API in Django
I am using Qoo10.jp api to publish the goods on Qoo10 store.
It working well but when I trying to delete a good it does not work.
I tried likes this in Django.
 params = {
     'key': user.qoo10_sak,
     'v': '1.0',
     'returnType': 'json',
     'method': 'ItemsBasic.DeleteGoods',
     'ItemCode': m_product.code,
 }
 response = requests.get('https://api.qoo10.jp/GMKT.INC.Front.QAPIService/ebayjapan.qapi', params)

 print(response.status_code)

When I print the response status_code it 200 but the response body is Can't find method Info Delete
How to solve this issue.
